# Redirect user after login through woocommerce login page to page with his/her username?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, login

As the title states I'm trying to redirect users after they log in through the woocommerce login form to their respective custom pages (http://example.com/accounts/username)

So far I got this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custo_login_redirect');
  function custo_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
  $redirect = site_url( '/accounts/' . $user->user_login );
  return $redirect;
}
```

but it is only redirecting to "http://example.com/accounts/" and not using the username in the url at all.

Is there a way to make it work? Thanks for any help.

Comment: perhaps user_login is not available, check with has_prop, and if not, you'll have to get the user object using the ID, from the link: //Note: If called with the "id" or "name" parameter, the constructor queries the wp_users table. If successful, the additional row data become properties of the object: user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name, spam (multisite only), deleted (multisite only). // https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#Public_Properties

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_wc_login_redirect', 10, 3);
  function custom_wc_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
  $redirect = site_url() . '/accounts/' . $user->user_login;
  return $redirect;
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thank you, this saved my life!